# URL to open iOS app in App Store web page and iTunes app simultaneously

Tags: html, ios, url, itunes

What is the preferred URL to use to open an iOS app in it's App Store web page as well as the iTunes app (when available on the host device)?

I've tried using the itms:// protocol but this opens the app details in the iTunes app only and so is of no use when the URL is navigated to from an Android or Windows phone for example.

Comment: Ok, I dont understand "as well as the iTunes app"...

Comment: Ok, for example, if you go to this web page for one of Agant's iOS apps (http://www.agant.com/app.php?appID=nre), the 'Available on the App Store' link navigates to the app details on the App Store web page and also launches the iTunes app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that the behaviour of a URL opening an iTunes preview web page before automatically opening the iTunes app on the host device (where available) is triggered by affiliate links (which need to track the click before taking the user to the intended destination).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would want to look at the browser to determine which link to use. If the browser is Safari on iOS device, give them the iTunes protocol link, otherwise, http://.

I believe javascript allows you to read such information: Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Comment: Ah that's a great bit of advice thank you, I will check that out.